# Android change background color of button when click pending

Tags: android, xml

Hello stackoverflow users, I am stuck with a sick problem.I have searched over the internet and on stackoverflow on many posts but I couldn't find the right answer to solve my problem.I want to change my background color of a button when is pressed to click.
I get error on the XML I want to use something like a new xml for the button and set 2 values for when pressed and the default color nothing else.I want to import the xml in the button background propertie.

the xml so far is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
      <item android:state_pressed="true" 
            android:background="#3399FF" />

      <item android:background="#3399FF" /> 
  </selector>
```

I get the error: `Failed to parse file C:\Users\marian.pavel\Desktop\tempwork\Sym_Temp_Dynamic\res\drawable\reset.xml`

Any ideeas how I can solve this problem ? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Valid XML file gives "failed to parse" error in Android ADT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721697/valid-xml-file-gives-failed-to-parse-error-in-android-adt)

Comment: Created a new file with other name, still some problem, I also tryed to import it in code.

Comment: And clean the project?

Comment: Yes, also cleaned the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is the exact xml, empty spaces can cause parsing errors. Remove any empty space or line break in first line of the xml, remove the empty space before  tags or copy paste this code, clean & build and try to run again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:background="#3399FF" />
    <item android:background="#3399FF" /> 
</selector>
```